# Order by 's' using WP_Query()

Tags: posts, wp-query, order

I have a wp query like this,

```
$args_search = array( 
 's' => "string1 string2 string3 ..",
 'post_type' => array( 'post' )
);

$wp_query = new WP_Query( $args_search );
```

This will search for  string1,string2,string3 etc.I need to list the result in the order of matching count , I mean the most number of matching post will list first and so on. Is it possible to list like this using `WP_Query()` without using any custom query?

Comment: Can you try to explain what order you want the results to be in more clearly?

Answer (score -1):

You can use [Relevanssi](https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/) plugin,

> Relevanssi replaces the default search with a partial-match search
>   that sorts results by relevance. It also indexes comments and
>   shortcode content.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/relevanssi/

- Search results sorted in the order of relevance, not by date.